# dplyr::tbl returning list instead of table

Tags: sql-server, dplyr, odbc, dbi, dbplyr

I am trying to use dplyr in RStudio to manipulate tables in MS SQL Server database. I successfully connected to the database using DBI, ODBC.

Code:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "myserver",
                 database = "ABC",
                 UID = "sqladmin",
                 PWD = "pwd",
                 port = '14333')

data <- tbl(con, "abc")
```

**abc** is a table within database **ABC**. The connection is successful (I am able look at the tables and fields) but dplyr::tbl is returning a list of 2 instead of returning the table **abc**. So **data** is a list instead of table. Where am I going wrong in this code?

The schema is **ABC** --> dbo --> **abc**

[image: image of data object]

Comment: Do you need data <- tbl(con, "abc") %>% collect()  ? I think dbplyr doesn't actually run a query and retrieve data until you collect().

Comment: Worked, thank you very much. Can I know if any manipulation on data object now will not affect the original table ?

Comment: Once the 'data' object is a tibble, no it won't. You've pulled the data into an object in your local R environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works as expected. What you’re seeing is simply a limitation of the type display in the RStudio data inspector: the actual type returned by `tbl` is an object of S3 class `tbl_SQLiteConnection` but it is implemented as a nested `list` (similar to how `data.frame`s are implemented as lists of columns).

You will be able to work with your `data` as expected. You can also invoke `as_tibble(data)` to get a proper tibble back … *but you don’t need to do that* to work with it!

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the question. So, if I want to manipulate the data using dplyr and SQL Server, I can directly use the data object but if I want to bring it into the R environment, I have to invoke ```collect()``` or ```as_tibble()```?

Comment: @user75252 Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Konrad's answer, some additional considerations:

- There is a distinction between a local dataframe and a remote dataframe.
  `remote_data <- tbl(connection, "database_table_name")` creates a remote data frame. The data is stored in the source database, but R has a pointer to the database that can be used for querying it.
- You can load data from a remote dataframe into R memory using `local_data <- collect(remote_data)` or `local_data <- as.dataframe(remote_data)`. Depending on the size of your remote data this can be very slow, or can crash R due to lack of memory.
- Both the local and the remote dataframe are dataframes. `class(remote_data)` and `class(local_data)` will return the expected type: `tbl` (a tibble). The remote dataframe is implemented as a list because it needs to store different info from the local dataframe. Try `head(remote_data, 100)` to view the first 100 rows of the remote table.
- Remote dataframes can be manipulated using (most) standard dplyr commands. These are translated by dbplyr into the corresponding database syntax and executed on the database.

A good use of remote tables is to perform initial filtering and summarizing of a large table before pulling the summarized data into local R memory for further processing. For example:

```r
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "server_name",
                 database = "database_name",
                 UID = "sqladmin",
                 PWD = "pwd",
                 port = '14333')

remote_data <- tbl(con, "database_table_name")

# preview remote table
head(remote_data)

# summarize
prepared_data <- remote_data %>%
  filter(column_1 >= 10) %>%
  group_by(column_2) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(column_2), .groups = 'drop')

# check query of prepared table
show_query(prepared_data)

# draw summarised table into local memory
local_summarised_data <- collect(prepared_data)
```

Edit: Some additional points following @mykonos' question:

- Storage of remote tables works differently from storage of local tables.

  In R the command `prepared_data <- local_table %>% mutate(new = 2 * old)` creates a separate copy of the source data (it is a little more complex than this because of lazy evaluation under the hood, but this is a sufficient way to think of it). If you were removing objects from your workspace with `rm` you would have to remote both copies.

  However, remote tables are not duplicate copies of the data on the database. The command `prepared_data <- remote_table %>% mutate(new = 2 * old)` creates a second remote table **in R**. This means we have two remote table objects in R both pointing back to the same database table (but in different ways).
- Remote table definitions in R are defined by two components: The database connection and the query the produces the current table. When we manipulate a remote table in R (by default) all we are doing is changing the query. You can use `show_query` to check the query that is currently defined.

  So, when we create `remote_data <- tbl(con, "database_table_name")` then `remote_data` is stored in R as the database connection and a query something like: `SELECT * FROM database_table_name`.

  When we create `prepared_data <- remote_table %>% mutate(new = 2 * old)` then `prepared_data` is stored in R as the same database connection as `remote_table` but a different query. Something like: `SELECT *, new = 2*old FROM database_table_name`.
- Changing remote table connections in R does not affect the database.   Because manipulations of remote connections only changes the query, working with database tables via dbplyr can not change the source data. This is consistent with the design and intention of databases.

  If you want to write to a database from R, there are a range of ways to do it. There are a number of questions tagged dbplyr on SO that ask about this.
- One downside of this approach is that lengthy manipulations of remote tables can perform poorly because the database has to do significant work to show the final result. I recommend you explore options to write temporary / intermediate tables if this is a concern.

Comment: Thank you for these details. Does performing manipulations (filtering, etc.) on "remote_data" frame affect the original table being called in the source database, or does it create a separate table in the DB? If the latter, where is the remote data frame created on the server? Is it something I would be able to see in SMSS? And do you have to clear these out when you're through using them?

Comment: A prepared remote table does not exist as a separate table in the database. In R it is stored as the query that produces the table - this is what `show_query(prepared_data)` reveals. So, the database is treated as read-only by default. You can write tables prepared tables back into the database (there are several questions about this on SO) but this has to be done deliberately.