# Convert Oracle table to dataframe in R

Tags: r, oracle, dplyr, dbplyr, tbl

I am trying to convert an Oracle database table into an "R" data frame.

I am using the `dplyr::tbl` function as well as `dbplyr::in_schmema` to connect to the specific schema and table within the Oracle database.

`Table <- dplyr::tbl(my_oracle, dbplyr::in_schema('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME'))`

This is the part that confuses me as the result is an object called "Table" that is a "List of 2" as seen below. The two items within the list are also lists of two.

[image]

I am able to convert this to a data frame by wrapping it with `as.data.frame` like this:

`Table2 <- as.dataframe(dplyr::tbl(my_oracle, dbplyr::in_schema('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME')))`

However, when I do this i takes a very long time (hours for some tables) to convert to a data frame. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve the outcome of converting the Oracle table into a usable data frame?

Also any insight into why dplyr::tbl results in a list of lists would also be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try [RJDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html) with `dbGetQuery`?

Comment: Thanks @MarmiteBomber. Unfortunately I can't use the RJDBC package as it is dependent on the Rjava package, which is blocked for use at my work.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to convert to dataframe? Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58099458/7742981

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr::tbl returning list instead of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58099458/dplyrtbl-returning-list-instead-of-table)

Comment: @Simon.S.A. Thanks this is exactly the question I had. Thanks for finding and sharing.

The reason I am trying to convert to a data.frame is so that I can use dplyr to perform some operations to further model some tables to create some materialized views. These tables are then written to excel using "write_xl".

The issue I am having is that when I bring them into the R environment using as.tibble(), as.data.frame() or collect() it takes a very long time  to load to the R environment.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the delay is because (1) you are loading a lot of data from the database, or (2) there is low bandwidth between the source database and R.

Comment: Better to use `collect()` with dplyr/dbplyr than `as.data.frame()` I think. How many rows and cols there are in your oracle table ? In this situation you can run `r dplyr::tbl(my_oracle, dbplyr::in_schema('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME')) %>% count()` before collect to see size of your data in rows, and  `r dplyr::tbl(my_oracle, dbplyr::in_schema('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME')) %>% glimpse()` to have an overview and get number of columns.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume but collect() seems to take just as long as as.data.frame().